# Getting Error while trying to read .csv in R Studio

Tags: r, read.csv, r-xlsx

I'm trying to import a dataset with .csv format but I keep getting errors.

If I use the built-in import feature of R Studio I get this error:

> embedded nul in the string:
> 'C\0a\0m\0p\0a\0g\0n\0e\0_\0N\0o\0C\0a\0g\0g\0i\0o\0_\0C\0o\0s\0t\0o\0>\00'*

If I use:

```
google_raw <- read.csv("google_raw.csv")

Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

But if I open the same file with Excel and save it as .XLSX and then try to import it's working fine

Is there a way to convert the .csv file to .xlsx without opening?

Ideally I want to download the file and run a script without the manual action of converting it and then run a script

Comment: quick and dirty: write a vba in excel that opens all csv and saves as xlsx

Comment: Sounds like a possible encoding problem. What language is `google_raw.csv` written in?

Comment: @jpiversen it's in standard english